# Suggest windows webhost provider for following requirements

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

We have a asp.net MVC3 based web app which uses **SQL SERVER 2008** for database. Also, we have a client side desktop application which also uses SQL SERVER 2008.
While developing the system, we are able to Sync tables using SQL SERVER **Replication** feature. Now, we want to host our site on a webserver but we are clueless about it.
If anyone of you have a similar system working then please suggest a cheap but reliable webhost which supports Replication.

Initially there will be approximately **10 or less clients** who will perform replication **2 or 3 times** a day.
The size of the database will be less than 4GB for sure.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of hosts out there. One who I've used, and who stays very current with MS technologies and has reasonable prices, is [discountASP.NET](http://discountasp.net/).

Comment: I have used discountASP.net.  They were good but I left at a time when they didn't offer a database server I wanted.  I think they do now.

Answer (score 0):

winhost.com is where I do some development work and host my personal stuff too.  They meet your needs.